# Gas Water Heater will be permanately out of service

Tags: water-heater

Gas Water Heater will be permanately out of service. Pilot & Gas is shutoff.
Should I drain the water or leave it or does it matter at all?

Comment: Is the water heater going to be disconnected from water supply?

Answer (score 2):

#### Drain it

Doesn't have to be bone dry, but if you drain it then you avoid the possibility of 40 gallons of water all over the place. It wouldn't be scalding hot, but it would still make a mess.

**Drain it.**

Comment: I agree I would drain it. A hose connected to the lower clean out it will drain.